# DD File Not Updating

Tags: truenas, dd

I am following this thread to guide me from FreeNas VirtualBox to bhyve.

https://blog.yuo.be/2017/01/04/migrating-a-vm-from-virtualbox-to-iohyve-bhyve-on-freenas-9-10/

However, I am stuck with this command.

```
dd if=/mnt/Main/jails/Production/tmp/SDB.Raw of=/dev/zvol/Tank/iohyve/SDB/Disk0
```

I cannot see any progress on the terminal, and when I use WinSCP to look at the file directory, disk0 size is 0 KB but the modified timestamp updates every second. The raw file is ~65gb.

I also notice that the Pool name is different on the between destinations. Does this matter?

Thanks

Update:

I tried running `rsync` and this is the output I got:

```
[root@Server] rsync --info=progress2 /mnt/Main/jails/Production/SDB.Raw /dev/zvol/Main/iohyve/SDB-Server/disk0
     32,768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 66,571,993,088 100%  144.63MB/s    0:07:18 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
rsync: mkstemp "/dev/zvol/Main/iohyve/SDB-Server/.disk0.Fwn6Co" failed: Operation not supported (45)
 66,571,993,088 100%  144.63MB/s    0:07:18 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1180) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill` command to follow your `dd` process (all in one line):

```
dd if=/path/to/file of=/path/to/newfile bs=512 & ddid=$!; while true; do sleep 1; kill -USR1 $ddid || break; sleep 5; done
```

If you have installed the coreutils 8.24, dd has a new option which enable to follow his progress :

```
status=progress
```

To verify your dd version :

```
dd --version
```

Comment: I used Rsync to get an update but am not getting an error message.

Comment: With dd you will never have an error message, you will just have the count of blocks copied at the end (or when it is killed) of the process. You can try dc3dd (https://sourceforge.net/projects/dc3dd/?SetFreedomCookie), it's the same thing like dd with more control during the process. You can calculate the hash and have a progress...

Answer (score 0):

`dd` doesn not output any progress status, just wait until it's finished. You have to make sure the paths are correct before starting.

Comment: After 30 minutes of letting it run, I should have seen the output file size increase larger than 0 KB?

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? For example I see a capital R in `SDB.Raw`. Sure that it is not `SDB.raw`? You can abort it with `ctrl - c`